# javascript - How to do replaceAll?

Tags: javascript, regex, replaceall

Hi I have a problem here. I am trying to replace all instances of `+` character in a string using javascript. What happens is that only the first instance is being changed.

Here is my code:

```
var keyword = "Hello+Word%+";
keyword = keyword.replace("+", encodeURIComponent("+"));
alert(keyword);
```

The output is `Hello%2BWord%+` when it should be `Hello%2BWord%%2B` because there are 2 instances of `+`.

You can check this on : http://jsfiddle.net/Wy48Z/

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the global flag.

Fixed for you at http://jsfiddle.net/rtoal/Wy48Z/1/

```
var keyword = "Hello+Word%+";
keyword = keyword.replace(/\+/g, encodeURIComponent("+"));
alert(keyword);​
```

Comment: So that what g is about. I always see that on lots of examples but I thought its just a random character.

Comment: Oh, sorry, should have added to the answer.  After the `/.../` you can place a modifier character such as s, g, or i.  g means do the replacement everywhere, i means case-insensitive.  You can look them up [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/).

Answer (score 1):

The javascript regex, which is done by putting the expresison inbetween two forward slashes like: `/<expression/`

If you want to replace all, simply append a `g` after the last one like:

`/<expression/g`

In your case, it would be `/\+/g`

Answer (score 1):

The cross-browser approach is to use a [regexp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/) with the `g` (global) flag, which means "process all matches of the pattern, not just the first":

```
keyword = keyword.replace(/\+/g, encodeURIComponent("+"));
```

Notice I prefix the plus sign with a backslash because it would otherwise have the special meaning of "match one or more of the preceding thing".